# Virtual Memory and sbrk

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

On a 32 bit Linux system, a process can access up to 4 GB of virtual address space; however, processes seem to be conservative in varying degrees in reserving any of that. So a program that uses malloc will occasionally grow its data segment by a syscall sbrk/brk. Even those pages aren't claimed in physical memory yet. What I don't fully understand is why we need to sbrk in the first place, why not just give me 4 GB address space avoiding any sbrk call, as until we touch/claim those blocks, it is essentially a free operation right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you memory-map a file (a very common thing to do under Linux)? It has to go somewhere in the address space, so there must be some means of defining "used" and "not used" parts.
Shared memory (which is really just mapping a file without an actual file) is the same. It has to go somewhere, and the OS must be sure it can place it without overwriting something.

Also, it is preferrable to maintain locality of reference for obvious (and less obvious) efficiency reasons. If you were allowed to just write to and read from any location in your address space, you can bet that some people would do just that.

Comment: "Shared memory (which is really just mapping a file without an actual file) is the same. It has to go somewhere, and the OS must be sure it can place it without overwriting something." I see what you're saying (I think), as malloc calls mmap (with anonymous and private) I believe and that may or may not call sbrk, but if on program init malloc has done brk(4gb) it removes the syscall to sbrk etc..  But you can not longer map additional memory map files or create shared memory with different flags. Right... I think I am starting to understand

Comment: "Also, it is preferrable to maintain locality of reference for obvious (and less obvious) efficiency reasons" But if I take some memory from say 1gb into 4gb block and say 3.9gb into the 4gb block, it probably will be close in physical memory once that fresh allocation is seg faulted in (just zeroing out right)?

Comment: It might, it might not. You cannot know.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of reasons that come to mind:

- You'd no longer get segfaults when accessing unmapped memory
- The [Translation lookaside buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) (TLB) would be larger, possibly requiring more time to set it up
- You'd have to unmap some of that memory anyway if you load in a new shared library or mmap() something